# How to add multiple functions to be run on the same event from different locations

Tags: javascript, events

So, this is my problem.
I want to be able to add "onevent"'s from different locations in the document. Better explained below.

Let's say I have an input with the trigger "onblur='alert(this.value)'"

```
<input type="text" onblur="alert(this.value)" id="MyInput" />
```

But maybe later I decide I want to add an extra event to be fired after the alert - also "onblur" from somewhere else in the DOM. Like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function attachOnBlurToSomething (id)
  {
    document.getElementById(id).onBlur = function () {
      alert("Another alert!");
    };
  }

  attachOnBlurToSomething ("MyInput");
</script>
```

All above is ofcourse just bull code. But the scenario is the same.
What would happen in this case is that I would get "Another alert!" on blur. But I would like both of them to run. Doesn't really matter in what order. Just how?

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](http://alert%28%22Another%20alert!%22%29;) (or [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) where necessary - in IE < 9):

```
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("blur", function() {
    alert("Another alert!");
}, false);
```

By doing it this way you can get rid of any inline event handlers (like your current `onblur` attribute), which are generally considered as bad practice.

It also means you can register as many event handlers as you like for the same event.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Though that was not really how I meant. The problem is actually that I DO want people to be able to use inline onblur even though I'm also attaching handlers to the same event. Is that possible?

Comment: @woobione - Yes, you can have both. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hBsAm/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing it that way but something else was not working. So I switched to the document.getElementById().onblur approach. Guess I'll switch back! :D Thanks again :)